# can't get google Calendar API to work in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, calendar

I need a **NodeJS** server with a google calendar API to retrieve events.

I'm using [google-calendar](https://github.com/wanasit/google-calendar) library and code sample,

```
var gcal = require('google-calendar');
var google_calendar = new gcal.GoogleCalendar(accessToken);

var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var passport = require('passport');
var gcal = require('google-calendar');

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: config.consumer_key,
        clientSecret: config.consumer_secret,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:8082/auth/callback",
        scope: ['openid', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        google_calendar = new gcal.GoogleCalendar(accessToken);
        console.log(google_calendar);

        return done(null, profile);
    }
));
```

My `config.js` file is as following:

```
var env = require('node-env-file');

env(__dirname + '/.env');

module.exports = {
    consumer_key: process.env.GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
}
```

Then I use a `.env` file with all the credentials:

```
SLACK_TOKEN = "xxxxxx"

GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxx"
GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxx"
```

Those credentials come from the `json` that I downloaded setting up the google calendar API from my google account like explained in the [google-guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs).

Now, when I run the script with `node index.js` command, I don't get any output a part from this:

> node index.js
>   body - parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json / urlencoded middlewares index.js: 37: 13
>   body - parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules / body - parser / index.js: 105: 29
>   express - session deprecated undefined resave option;
>   provide resave option index.js: 38: 13
>   express - session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option;
>   provide saveUninitialized option index.js: 38: 13

So, no `console.log` output apparently. What am I missing?

Comment: did you found an answer?